# OpenRasta IIS6 Intermittent HTTP 404

Tags: iis-6, asp.net-4.0, openrasta

**Background**

I have an API built with OpenRasta that serves JSON-encoded data to an HTML/AJAX enabled interface.

**Problem**

When hosted with IIS 6, I'm experiencing intermittent 404 errors when a resource is queried. Everything works well after an application pool restart; after a few successful requests the 404 errors start and persist until the app pool is recycled. I have confirmed ISAPI mapping is set in IIS 6, what am I missing?

**Trace output for intermittent failed request**

```
Unregistering host of type OpenRasta.Hosting.AspNet.AspNetHost
```

**Trace output for successful request for comparison (namespace and resource URIs redacted)**

```
Registering host of type OpenRasta.Hosting.AspNet.AspNetHost
Using dependency resolver of type OpenRasta.DI.InternalDependencyResolver.
Registering host's root dependencies..
Using dependency registrar of type OpenRasta.Configuration.DefaultDependencyRegistrar..
Ignoring constructor, following dependencies didn't have a registration:OpenRasta.TypeSystem.Surrogates.ISurrogateBuilder[].
Registering host's leaf dependencies..
Using configuration source <namespace>.api.Configuration.
Ignoring constructor, following dependencies didn't have a registration:System.Func`1[System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[OpenRasta.Configuration.MetaModel.Handlers.IMetaModelHandler]].
Ignoring constructor, following dependencies didn't have a registration:System.Diagnostics.TraceSource.
Ignoring constructor, following dependencies didn't have a registration:OpenRasta.OperationModel.MethodBased.IMethodFilter[].
Incoming host request for http://<resource URI>.
Adding communication context data.
Entering OpenRastaRewriterHandler: Rewriting to original path.
Entering OpenRastaIntegratedHandler: Request for http://<resource URI>.
Incoming host request for http://<resource URI>.
Adding communication context data.
Found 1 operation(s) with a matching name..
Found 0 operation(s) with matching [HttpOperation] attribute..
Operation <handler>::Get() selected with 0 required members and 0 optional members, without request codec.
Ignoring constructor, following dependencies didn't have a registration:OpenRasta.OperationModel.Interceptors.IOperationInterceptor[].
Executing OperationResult OperationResult: type=OK, statusCode=200..
Selected codec JsonDataContractCodec out of 1 codecs for entity of type List`1 and negotiated media type application/json; q=0.5..
Codec JsonDataContractCodec selected..
Entering ResponseEntityWriterContributor: Generating response entity..
Setting Content-Length to 133.
Exiting ResponseEntityWriterContributor.
Writing http headers..
Exiting OpenRastaIntegratedHandler.
Exiting OpenRastaRewriterHandler.
Request finished..
```

---

OpenRasta.Hosting.AspNet.dll built from [GitHub master](https://github.com/openrasta/openrasta-hosting-aspnet):
[image: OpenRasta.Hosting.AspNet.dll version]

Comment: What version of hosting are you using?

Comment: Ok, do you know what type of 404 you're getting? Does it come from OR or is it IIS or asp.net or something else that triggers it? (aka when you get the 404, is there any OR log at all confirming that OR gets the request?). You may want to upgrade to a more recent 2.1 version of the hosting.

Comment: I should clarify, the project version used to build is 2.1.1. Version reported by dll built from 2.1.1 is 2.0.3.0, as seen in attached screenshot. Should these version numbers be the same? Working on getting the OR logs. May need some direction in capturing these, but I'll try it out first.

Comment: They should be the same but the build script is out of date :) You can get the OR logs by attaching a debugger or configuring a tracesource for openrasta in the app. I'd recommend rebuilding openrasta and openrasta-hosting-aspnet from the master branches on github, they have a bunch of fixes for "unregistering host" issues, some stupid code from me made it in hosting at some point.